# Tableau cannot horizontally scroll in worksheets

Tags: scroll, scrollbar, tableau-api

I am using Tableau for data visualization and generating lists that can be exported to Excel.

However, when the amount of columns get too big, I cannot see all my columns in the view (They are there though). The problem is that **there doesn't seem to be a horizontal scrollbar**. I can scroll vertically through my rows, but I haven't found a way to do this horizontally to look through my columns, the same way you would do at the data source tab.

If anyone could help me to figure out how to achieve this that would be awesome! I am using Tableau Desktop version 2018.3 on a Mac.

**Edit:** The problem also seems to be on Windows and is not related to the maximum amount of columns or the view mode.

Example image of the described problem

[image]

Comment: How many columns in your dashboard? Only 16 Maximum columns to allowed, which is the limit.

Comment: The problem is actually not related to the amount of columns. On small screens the problem arises when the amount of columns is way below Tableau's maximum. E.g. when there are 12 columns, I could see only the first 8, and cannot scroll to columns 9-12.

P.S. If you want to have more than 16 columns, there is actually a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637417/how-to-display-40-columns-in-tableau/29149059%2329149059) available.

Comment: Will  you share the snapshot of your dashboard

Comment: Added a snapshot of the problem I'm facing @MehulKatara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting scrollbar because you are viewing it on a worksheet. Try putting it on the dashboard and set dashboard size to fixed and increase width to accommodate all columns.
now you will get horizontal scrollbar for sure

thanks

Comment: This actually worked for me. Once the sheet was on a dashboard with a fixed width that was big enough, the scrollbar appeared and I could scroll to the end. Thanks a lot for your suggestion @Vishal!

Answer (score 1):

Besides updating the horizontal row/column label limit @Bernardo mentioned here: [image]

[image]

You'll need to make sure you've have selected "Standard" from the display option list at the top of the screen. That options prevent Tableau from fitting everything into the height, width or view of your current display.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my view is already on Standard and the problem doesn't actually relate to the maximum amount of columns. The maximum is at 16 already, but I simply cannot see further than my screen size allows me to.

Comment: And you don't get a scrollbar, right? If your table extends path the width of your screen and your display is set to "Standard" you should be able to scroll to see the overflow. What's different between your screen and the images I shared? It might help if you share a couple of screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Tableau shows a horizontal scroll bar for measures, **but not for dimensions**. When only dimensions are included on either the Columns or Rows shelf, the lower horizontal scroll bar will not display. Dimensions are treated as headers for measure aggregations and do not generate a horizontal scroll bar when they exceed the width of the view.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Do you also have a suggested workaround for working with too many dimensions perhaps?

Comment: As an alternative, you can drag dimensions to Detail. When you drag dimensions to Detail, they will appear in the marks' tooltip. Tooltips can be formatted and customized to contain multiple dimensions in any order desired.

Answer (score 0):

To change the Table Layout and increase the number of columns and rows in your table, go to:

- Analysis > Table Layout > Advanced

Set each of the Maximum values to 16, which is the limit allowed.